# The make on FreeBSD doesn't support "ifdef" directives

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, freebsd

My `FreeBSD` is `11.0`, and find the `make` can't process the `ifdef` directives. For example:

```
ifdef VERBOSE
Q :=
else
Q := @
endif
```

The `make` will complain:

```
make: "/root/Project/powermon/Makefile" line 13: Need an operator
make: "/root/Project/powermon/Makefile" line 15: Need an operator
make: "/root/Project/powermon/Makefile" line 17: Need an operator
```

My current solution is using `gmake` instead. So does any `make` port on `FreeBSD` support processing `ifdef`?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense: if you are using `gmake`, there **is** a make port on FreeBSD that supports `ifdef`: `gmake`, that is GNU make, probably the most used implementation of make. Why don't you create an alias (if you want to name it `make`) and use it?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet First I use `make`, find it doesn't work. So I switch to `gmake`. I just wonder whether there is some `make` or not. you comment: "gmake, that is GNU make, probably the most used implementation of make. " clarify my confusion, thx!

Comment: On your system GNU make seems to be installed and working. Your only (apparent problem) is that it is named `gmake`, not `make`. Search a bit about aliases, create one named `make` that points to `gmake` and voilà. Or create a symbolic link, as you wish, and set your PATH such that it comes first.

Comment: No, please don't alias GNU make to `make` on a BSD system. The default `make` in BSD is a BSD make, which has different syntax and supports different things than GNU make. Only very basic `make` features are common between those two flavors of `make`.

Comment: @NanXiao for your immediate question: In BSD make, make instructions start with a period (`.`) and although BSD make has a different set of functionality, a `.ifdef` exists. Please [see this fine manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)) (in general, FreeBSD comes with very well-written and *complete* manual pages).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BSD make uses different syntax and has different features than GNU make. The snippet you show should look like the following for BSD make:

```
.ifdef VERBOSE
Q :=
.else
Q := @
.endif
```

You have basically three options:

1. If your software targets specifically BSD, write your Makefile in BSD make syntax. [man make(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)) has the complete manual for FreeBSD's `make`.
2. Write a *portable Makefile*. This would only use the *most basic* features of `make` that every known `make` tool implements (e.g. don't use any pattern rules etc). This can be tedious and there are other tools helping to manage this by *generating* the Makefile like `cmake` or the *GNU autotools*.
3. write a GNU make Makefile (might be a good idea to name it `GNUmakefile`, so it is never interpreted by any other `make` than GNU make) and rely on the fact that GNU make is available nearly everywhere. For FreeBSD, this would mean installing the appropriate port.

---

If you go with the third option, you can add a "wrapper" `Makefile` like e.g. this:

```
GNUMAKE?= gmake

all:
    ${GNUMAKE} $@

.DEFAULT:
    ${GNUMAKE} $@

.PHONY: all
```

Typing `make` on BSD will cause the BSD make to read this file and accordingly call `gmake`. On a GNU system (where `make` is GNU make), this file will be ignored when there is a `GNUmakefile` -- GNU make prefers this over just `Makefile`.

Comment: I would add that it's generally simpler to just use BSD-style Makefiles and recommend [bmake](http://crufty.net/help/sjg/bmake.htm) for non-BSD systems.

Comment: That's even another option, but which one is "simpler" probably depends on which features you use and are used to ;)

Comment: I just mean that GNU make is the outlier, and on top of that, very few people write Makefiles for GNU make. In that sense, certainly BSD make is far more popular.

Comment: A few further points: 1. FreeBSD changed to BSD Make around 10.0. In 9.x and lower it's FreeBSD's make which is different than the current one (from netbsd).  2. You can name your makefiles as BSDMakefile similar to how the GNU one works and it will keep GNU make from running them!  

Some versions of FreeBSD still include fmake which is the old make in case you need to target old releases. 3. Not all BSDs use the same make. MidnightBSD uses fmake by default and bmake is available but not named make in recent versions. FreeBSD also modified bmake in a few ways so it does not match NetBSD's

Answer (score 0):

A more portable way to write something like that is:

```
Q$(VERBOSE) := @
```